# nvidia-smi shows GPU utilization when it's unused

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I'm running tensorflow on GPU id 1 using `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`, everything in nvidia-smi looks good, my python process is running on gpu 1, memory and power consumption show GPU 1 is in use.

But oddly GPU 0, which is unused (based on the process list, memory, power usage, and common sense) shows 96% Volatile GPU-Utilization.

Anyone know why?

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.48                 Driver Version: 367.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K20c          Off  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| 30%   41C    P0    53W / 225W |      0MiB /  4742MiB |     96%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K20c          Off  | 0000:43:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| 36%   49C    P0    95W / 225W |   4516MiB /  4742MiB |     63%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1      5193    C   python                                        4514MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: are you the only one using the system ?  Seems also a bogus report because the Memory Usage is 0 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `ps aux | grep 5193` to see which program is using the GPU.

Your GPUs have ECC enabled, so you will see high CPU or memory utilization.

> During driver initialization when ECC is enabled one can see high GPU and Memory Utilization readings. This is caused by ECC Memory Scrubbing mechanism that is performed during driver initialization.
>     When Persistence Mode is Disabled, driver deinitializes when there are no clients running (CUDA apps or nvidia-smi or XServer) and needs to initialize again before any GPU application (like nvidia-smi) can query its state thus causing ECC Scrubbing.
>   As a rule of thumb always run with Persistence Mode Enabled. Just run as root `nvidia-smi -pm 1`. This will speed up application lunching by keeping the driver always loaded.

Reference: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/539632/k20-with-high-utilization-but-no-compute-processes-/

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to explain it. Process 5193 is my process running on GPU 1 though, it was only GPU 0 that was looking odd.